# Ajax post data through name

Tags: php, ajax

If I add caption to image it's working, if I add one more caption without refreshing the page the 1st value is posting to the second one...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cap_btn").click(function(){
        var li = $(this).closest("li");
        var cap = $('input[name="cap"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addcap.php",
            data: { id: li.data("imageId"), "cap": cap},
            success: function(data){
                alert("Caption Added");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $ids = $_POST['id'];
    $cap = $_POST['cap'];
    try
    {

        $query = "UPDATE image SET caption='$cap' WHERE id='$ids'";
        $sql=$con->prepare($query);
        $sql->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue / problem / question ?

Comment: I'm not getting any data in addcap.php page...

Comment: Do you mean `data: { id: li.data("imageId"), cap: cap}`?

Comment: @chad yes, I want to send id and cap to another php page

Comment: Check the value of the variables you're sending are actually populated in JS beforehand. Check your network tab in the browser to see what values are being sent to the server, and in what format. Check that your server-side is asking for the variables by the correct, case-sensitive names from the POST vars, and check that your button is not doing a default postback as well as the ajax call. In other words, do some basic debugging. You already have all the tools you need to pinpoint the problem accurately.

Comment: And the value of cap is from the `$('input[name="cap"]').val();`?

Comment: @chad yes.......

Comment: Can you post your php code here. Thanks!

Comment: @chad updated the php code

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO.

Comment: what does "the 1st value is posting to the second one..." mean, exactly? Preferably give an example, and show some sample HTML. have you got multiple controls with the `name="cap"` attribute? `.val()` will only ever get the value of the first one. If you need to get a specific one, you'll have to given them unique IDs, or restrict your search to a specific area of the DOM.

Comment: Show your form too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".cap_btn").click(
    function()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                alert("Caption Added");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("failure");
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "addcap.php", true);

        var formdata = new FormData();

        var li = $(this).closest("li");
        var cap = $('input[name="cap"]').val();

        formdata.append("id",li.data("imageId"));
        formdata.append("cap",li.data("cap"));

        xmlhttp.send(formdata);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: why falling back to native XMLHTTP when jquery ajax is available, and is much neater?

Comment: Because jquery uses it anyways, and in my opinion this looks better

Comment: it does use it (it must), but it also does quite a lot more than that as well, a lot of which is extremely useful, and arguably it improves the syntax and flow, making the code a bit more comprehensible. This is about the most basic ajax implementation there could be. It's not wrong, of course, just an odd choice IMO. A library is available which removes a lot of the potential pitfalls of using XHR, wraps it up neatly, it's there and available, but you don't use it. Do you reproduce all this boilerplate in your code every time you make an ajax request?

Comment: Sometimes i write this code, sometimes i use other libraries, but it's not the point, i wrote it like this just to see if it is a problem in his javascript code or php code.

Comment: ok but functionally it's no different to the original, just using different syntax. So how would that solve the problem? If you believe it would, then add an explanation to the answer, because it's not obvious.